# SQL Select statement from a webpage control and check relevant check boxes according to result

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio

I have a sql select statement in my VS2005 C# server-side coding for a web application and I am meeting some errors.

Below is a screenshot of the controls in the webpage:
[image]

---

**Data Source** *SqlDataSource1* : Query:`SELECT [Name] FROM [Users]`.

**Dropdownlist** *UserNameList* : Lists all `userName` retrieved from `SqlDataSource1`.

**Checkboxes** *AdminCb* and *UserCb*  : Automatically checks if the `userType` of the `userName` is as.

**Button** *loadUser* : Gets the user type and checks the check boxes accordingly.

---

Below is my code for my *loadUser* button

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DATASOURCE");
    string sql = string.Format("SELECT [User Type] FROM [Users] where Name like " + UserNameList.Text);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    if(sql== "Administrator"){
        AdminCb.Checked=true;
    }
    if(sql== "User"){
        UserCb.Checked=true;
    }
```

---

Currently I am stuck with the error (*Wong* is the 2nd word of the user's name):

[image]

---

Questions:

1) How can change my Sql query so that it can take in more than 1word?

2) And will I be able to check boxes once I am able to run my sql query?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have to use `Parameter` and call the `ExecuteScalar()` method instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

```
 string sql = "SELECT [User Type] FROM [Users] where [Name]=@Name";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name",SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value=UserNameList.Text;
 conn.Open();
 Object result=cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 conn.Close();

 if(result!=null)
  {
     string usertype=result.ToString();
     if(usertype=="Administrator")
       {}
     else
       {}
  }
```

In case, if result returned from the database contains more then one `rows` then use `ExecuteReader()` method.

```
 string sql = "SELECT [User Type] FROM [Users] where [Name] like @Name";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name",SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value="%" + UserNameList.Text + "%";
 conn.Open();
 SqlDataReader result=cmd.ExecuteReader();
 while(result.Read())
 {
    ///
   }
 result.Close();
 conn.Close();
```

Comment: thanks for the help. my webpage now runs without any error now. but is there any way I could store the variable *sql* into a string variable to make sure that the `User Type` has been successfully retrieved?

Comment: Do you want to store returned result? Use session if you want to use it across the web-app.

Comment: I just want to check of the result is 'Administrator' or 'User', and there will only be one returned records, so it is just a simple check to see whether sql stores 'Administrator' or 'User', and if it is administrator, check the admin checkbox, and if it is user, check the user checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are concatenating the SQL string, if the input itself has a single quote in it, it thinks this is the end of the input, and the continuing input is SQL statements, which is why you may be getting that error.

Switch to using a parameter, or make sure any single quotes are escaped as a pair of single quotes, like:

```
string sql = string.Format("SELECT [User Type] FROM [Users] where Name like " + UserNameList.Text.Replace("'", "''"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is indicating there is something wrong with the Name, I would take a closer look at this line:

```
string sql = string.Format("SELECT [User Type] FROM [Users] where Name like " + UserNameList.Text);
```

If you are using `string.Format`, you might as well *use* it

```
string sql = string.Format("SELECT [User Type] FROM [USERS] where Name like {0}", UserNameList.Text);
```